# Replace/regex: Put span tags around numbers that are followed by %

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to sorround all numbers in a string (numbers that are followed by % sign) in span tags

Here are some regex noob attempts at solving it:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(1-9+)%/", "<span>$1</span>", $str);
```

or

```
$str = preg_replace("/([1-9]+)%/", "<span>$1</span>", $str);
```

Nothing is replaced

I bet I have got it all wrong.. I need to learn regex more, I know

But can you help me further with this?

Comment: The second one is correct. You'll have to elaborate on your usage, code context, input and output (did you actually *view source* the page result?) to receive any advise.

Comment: Yes I tried view source. I also tried strictly setting $str as "hello 100% hello" to see if that did anything different. Nothing is replaced

Comment: Is the second one really correct? It felt pretty random/incorrect when I wrote it (just wrote what I thought would be ok)

Comment: Second one is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct but there is one crucial glitch. You are matching `[1-9]` instead of `[0-9]`.

**EDIT:** Use of `preg_replace_callback` to generate random number:

Following should work:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/([0-9]+)%/', function ($m) { 
       return '<span>' . rand($m[1]-5, $m[1]+5) . '%</span>'; }, 'hello 100% hello');
```

Comment: Yes I discovered some flaws too (see my answer)

Comment: Does it not matter if I put the % inside or outside the ) ?

Comment: If you don't want `%` in the resulting `span` string then leave it outside matched group.

Comment: Ok thanks. I also need to replace the number with a random number that is from -5 to +5 of the original number. Is there a quick easy way to do this inside the preg_replace?

Comment: Wow, that is awesome. And complex (for me). Thank you very much :) I will try to learn from it. I just needed to add the % sign at the span

Comment: Yup that is fine (I updated). You can check docs of `preg_replace_callback` for more info.

Comment: I need to buy some books and get better at this. Every time I need regex I'm at loss ;)

Comment: PHP manuals are pretty good and don't forget SO community help :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying some more, this works:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[0-9]{1,3}%/', '<span>$0</span>', $str);
```

Using () was first mistake. Using 1-9 instead of 0-9 was other mistake. Using $1 instead of $0 was third mistake (I think)

Comment: Just use `([0-9]+%)`.